# Drupal menu_attributes parent classes

Tags: drupal, menu, hyperlink

So I'm using menu_attributes (http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) to add specific classes to my menu items.
A problem for me is that these are added to the link itself

```
<li class="leaf active menu-mlid-873><a class="customClass active" href="/">Home</a></li>
```

But I would like to somehow make it like this, so that the class is also used for the parent of the link

```
<li class="customClass leaf active menu-mlid-873><a class="customClass active" href="/">Home</a></li>
```

I tried using `theme_menu_alter` but can't seem to figure out how I can get the class from there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override the theme_menu_link function. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7

Comment: That's actually what I used, but I can't find out how to use the classes from the `menu_attributes`, `$output` just returns the entire `<a>`

Comment: My bad, that was actually located inside `$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class']`